# Convert from predefined type to own CMyString

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let's say I have a function called dummy defined in the following way:

```
void dummy(CMyString& mystr)
{
   mystr.print(); //show
}
```

CMyString would be my own implementation of strings using an array of chars.

```
int main()
{
   dummy("This is a test!");
   return 0;
}
```

I'd like the following program to print out : "This is a test!".
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, you just need to provide a non-`explicit` conversion constructor to `CMyString`:

```
class CMyString
{
public:
    CMyString(const char* x); 
    //.....
};
```

and, of course, implement the `CMyString::print` method. After this you need to change the parameter to

```
void dummy(const CMyString& mystr)
```

(and mark the `print` method as `const`) because you can't bind a temp to a non-const reference.

Comment: the dummy function accepts input by reference, does the compiler pre instantiate a temporary CMyString object before passing the reference to the dummy function?

Comment: @firexzanderr I was just adding that. You need a const reference.

Comment: Very good.  Where could I find such info & more advanced on c++ classes for further reading? Multumesc.

Comment: @firexzanderr vezi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. You just need to define a constructor for `CMyString` that takes an array of `char`s or a pointer to `char` as its sole argument. Like so:

```
class CMyString
{
public:
  CMyString(const char* str)
  {
    // Initialise CMyString with str
  }
};
```